# How to set a value to variable based on multiple conditions using Java Streams API?

Tags: java, if-statement, java-stream

I couldn't wrap my head around writing the below condition using Java Streams. Let's assume that I have a list of elements from the periodic table. I've to write a method that returns a String by checking whether the list has Silicon or Radium or Both. If it has only Silicon, method has to return `Silicon`. If it has only Radium, method has to return `Radium`. If it has both, method has to return `Both`. If none of them are available, method returns `""` (default value).

Currently, the code that I've written is below.

```java
String resolve(List<Element> elements) {
    AtomicReference<String> value = new AtomicReference<>("");
    elements.stream()
            .map(Element::getName)
            .forEach(name -> {
                if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("RADIUM")) {
                    if (value.get().equals("")) {
                        value.set("RADIUM");
                    } else {
                        value.set("BOTH");
                    }
                } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("SILICON")) {
                    if (value.get().equals("")) {
                        value.set("SILICON");
                    } else {
                        value.set("BOTH");
                    }
                }
            });
    return value.get();
}
```

I understand the code looks messier and looks more imperative than functional. But I don't know how to write it in a better manner using streams. I've also considered the possibility of going through the list couple of times to filter elements `Silicon` and `Radium` and finalizing based on that. But it doesn't seem efficient going through a list twice.

NOTE : I also understand that this could be written in an imperative manner rather than complicating with streams and atomic variables. I just want to know how to write the same logic using streams.

Please share your suggestions on better ways to achieve the same goal using Java Streams.

Comment: Element {
    String name;
    int atomicNumber;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be done with *Stream IPA* in a **single statement** and without *multiline lambdas*, *nested conditions* and *impure function* that changes the state outside the lambda.

My approach is to introduce an **enum** which elements correspond to all possible outcomes with its constants `EMPTY`, `SILICON`, `RADIUM`, `BOTH`.

All the return values apart from empty string can be obtained by invoking the method `name()` derived from the `java.lang.Enum`. And only to caver the case with empty string, I've added `getName()` method.

Note that since **Java 16** enums can be declared *locally* inside a method.

The logic of the **stream pipeline** is the following:

- stream *elements* turns into a stream of *string*;
- gets filtered and transformed into a stream of *enum constants*;
- reduction is done on the enum members;
- optional of enum turs into an optional of string.

Implementation can look like this:

```
public static String resolve(List<Element> elements) {
    return elements.stream()
            .map(Element::getName)
            .map(String::toUpperCase)
            .filter(str -> str.equals("SILICON") || str.equals("RADIUM"))
            .map(Elements::valueOf)
            .reduce((result, next) -> result == Elements.BOTH || result != next ? Elements.BOTH : next)
            .map(Elements::getName)
            .orElse("");
}
```

**enum**

```
enum Elements {EMPTY, SILICON, RADIUM, BOTH;
    String getName() {
        return this == EMPTY ? "" : name(); // note name() declared in the java.lang.Enum as final and can't be overridden
    }
}
```

**main**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(resolve(List.of(new Element("Silicon"), new Element("Lithium"))));
    System.out.println(resolve(List.of(new Element("Silicon"), new Element("Radium"))));
    System.out.println(resolve(List.of(new Element("Ferrum"), new Element("Oxygen"), new Element("Aurum")))
                .isEmpty() + " - no target elements"); // output is an empty string
}
```

**output**

```
SILICON
BOTH
true - no target elements
```

**Note:**

- Although with streams you can produce the result in **O(n)** time iterative approach might be better for this task. Think about it this way: if you have a list of `10.000` elements in the list and it starts with `"SILICON"` and `"RADIUM"`. You could easily break the loop and return `"BOTH"`.
- **Stateful** operations in the streams has to be avoided [according to the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Statelessness), also to understand why **javadoc** warns against stateful streams you might take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53329809/why-atomicinteger-based-stream-solutions-are-not-recommended). If you want to play around with `AtomicReference` it's totally fine, just keep in mind that this approach is not considered to be good practice.

I guess if I had implemented such a method with streams, the overall logic would be the same as above, but without utilizing an *enum*. Since only a single object is needed it's a **reduction**, so I'll apply `reduce()` on a stream of strings, extract the reduction logic with all the conditions to a *separate method*. Normally, *lambdas* have to be well-readable *one-liners*.

Answer (score 0):

i have used predicate in filter to for radium and silicon and using the resulted set i am printing the result.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Element> elementss = new ArrayList<>();
        Set<String> stringSet = elementss.stream().map(e -> e.getName())
            .filter(string -> (string.equals("Radium") || string.equals("Silicon")))
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
        if(stringSet.size()==2){
            System.out.println("both");
        }else if(stringSet.size()==1){
            System.out.println(stringSet);
        }else{
            System.out.println(" ");
        }
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Collect the strings to a unique set. Then check containment in constant time.

```
Set<String> names = elements.stream().map(Element::getName).map(String::toLowerCase).collect(toSet());
boolean hasSilicon = names.contains("silicon");
boolean hasRadium = names.contains("radium");
String result = ""; 
if (hasSilicon && hasRadium) {
  result = "BOTH";
} else if (hasSilicon) {
  result = "SILICON";
} else if (hasRadium) {
  result = "RADIUM";
}
return result;
```

Comment: Is there any other way than using `if-else` construct?

Comment: What do you mean? Your own question is using if-else. I don't see any other way to check one string or the other

Comment: @VivekTS: Not really, no.  Certainly nothing as efficient.

Comment: @LouisWasserman There might be a way to use XOR and a bitmap of the periodic table, maybe?

Comment: I would have tried a lookup in a `Map<Set<String>, String>`.

Answer (score 0):

You could save a few lines if you use regex, but I doubt if it is better than the other answers:

```
String resolve(List<Element> elements) {
    String result = elements.stream()
                            .map(Element::getName)
                            .map(String::toUpperCase)
                            .filter(str -> str.matches("RADIUM|SILICON"))
                            .sorted()
                            .collect(Collectors.joining());

    return result.matches("RADIUMSILICON") ? "BOTH" : result;
}
```